# JWT - how is signature calculated

Tags: encryption, jwt

https://jwt.io/ has the following example of a jwt token:

eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ

However if I use http://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html to do an HMAC SHA 256 signing of:

eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9

(using the secret key "secret"), it gives me this as the signature:

4c9540f793ab33b13670169bdf444c1eb1c37047f18e861981e14e34587b1e04

What do I do to get the correct signature:

TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ

Comment: The result you are getting is hex.  The result you want is base64.  Decode the hex to raw data then encode it to base64.  Or if you feel like it, do it directly.

Comment: Thanks Luke - if you put this as the answer I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you have is hexadecimal.  The result you are after is encoded as base64.

You simply need to convert the hex to raw data and then encode that into base64.  I didn't check to see if the values were actually the same but this is the most likely problem!